# jQuery and functions

Tags: jquery-ui

I have two questions

1) am having 5 div's each containing an image (single). when i click on individual  specifying their id then there is no problem like the code below....

```
$("#asadone").click(function()
{
    alert("xxxx");
})
$("#asadtwo").click(function()
{
    alert("yyyy");
})
```

But the problem lies when I try call it using function()

```
function alrt(x)
{
    $("# '+x+' ").click(function()
    $('#'+x).click(function()
    {
        alert("x");
    })
}
```

the html snippet, where this function is getting called,

```
<div id="asadone" class="addico cursor" onclick="alrt(asadone)"></div>.
```

2) ok when the particular div is clicked , I need its data to be appended to the row in another table...

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what the jQuery `click` method is. You should not be putting it within a function like this. Take a look at how to attach a `click` event to a class name.

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in your **selector**, try this:

```
function alrt(x)
{
    $("#" + x).click(function() // Was an error here
    {
        alert("x");
    })
}
```

If you pass a string you need to use **quotes**:

```
<div id="asadone" class="addico cursor" onclick="alrt('asadone')"></div>.
```

**Better way:**

```
function alrt(x)
{
    $(this).click(function()
    {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    })
}
```

and

```
<div id="asadone" class="addico cursor" onclick="alrt()"></div>.
```

If you want to attach the event automatically when the page loads and not when a user first click, you can remove the `onclick` attribute in your HTML and use this JavaScript:

```
$(".addico").click(function() {
   alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: function alrt(x)
  {
   alert($(x).attr("id"));
  }
if I need to find an id of specific div...

& the html snippet is,
 <div id="asadone" class="addico cursor" onclick="alrt(this)"></div>

Comment: I have updated my answer. Basically replace `x` by `$(this)` to get the element in the current context